# Edittext imeOptions actionDone not working with digits attribute?

Tags: android, android-edittext, imeoptions

I have an Editext . It contains attribute digits and imeOptions (actionDone) together.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:digits="1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz....."
        android:hint="@string/item_name"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:maxLines="1" />
```

The actionDone (Done button in Softkeyword) not found while using digit && imeOptions attributes together . We can only find enter button which doesn't make any focus change. I have tried it by skipping digit attribute , then imeOptions working correctly. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 29):

Just add singleLine="true" to your edittext

```
  android:singleLine = "true"
```

Comment: Single line is depricated . That's why I am using maxLines = 1

Comment: @TijoJoseph maxLines really working for you? It allowed more than one line for me.. thats the reason I use this deprecated code

Comment: @TijoJoseph, singleLine is not the same as maxLines=1. They do different job, so singleLine is still frequently used.

Comment: Thank you so much! This mysterious bug gave me lots of headache. How come you even find out this?

Comment: @SamuelT.Chou It's not from Mars. It's available from API 1. I am using it for seven years.

Comment: Though it is deprecated, it gets the job done.

Answer (score 16):

Use `setRawInputType()` on your EditText View

```
view.setRawInputType(view.getInputType() & ~EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE)
```

It is important to call `setRawInputType()` and not `setInputType()`, since the latter will set the keylistener based on the inputmethod and your `android:digits` attribute will be discarded. `setRawInputType()`  will only change the inputmethod and it won't touch the KeyListener, furthermore `& ~EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE` will disable the multi line mode, so no return key will be visible, instead your chosen imeOption should be visible.

Basically, there is a different behavior of singleLine and maxLines.

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: **This answer must be marked as accepted!** The `~EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE` works even if `android:inputType` and `android:digits` are defined!

Comment: As the only answer I've found that doesn't use the deprecated singleLine, this deserves more upvotes

Comment: view.setRawInputType(view.getInputType() & ~EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE)


you can set edittext.setRawInputType(edittext.getInputType() & ~EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE)

Tested it works! on lousy Mi devices, that using ContextThemeWrapper with NumberFormatException error can try this.

Any soft keyboard that doesn't work when IME_ACTION_DONE is set but keyboard doesnt disappear and trigger IME_ACTION_DONE can try this !

This solution is working!

Answer (score 1):

My testing with "android:digits" seems to cause problems in edittext fields and when setting imeOptions to android:imeOptions="actionDone" I could not get the "Done" button to appear on the keyboard.

Once I used

```
android:inputType="text"
```

without digits setting, the keyboard then presented "Done" (or a tick depending on your device's keyboard), and I could then capture the key stroke using:

```
editextField.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                int result = actionId & EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION;
                switch(result) {
                    case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE:
                        // put your code here.
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can programmatically set :

```java
EditText edit = view.findViewById(R.id.memo_edit_text);
edit.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
edit.setImeActionLabel("DONE", EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
edit.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

On the EditText that you want to associate with an IME Action
It works for textMultiLine and with any digits, just chose your action

credits : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52503760/11858207

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can also set

```
isSingleLine = true
```